# SugarCRM 7: Call BaseFilterLayout.applyFilter() method outside event context

Tags: javascript, sugarcrm

I'm working on a customization for Sugar Professional 7.2.x that pushes a filter from an auxiliary script into the filter function for the list view page. By setting a breakpoint inside the applyFilter function and exporting the function itself as a member of the global object, I can then call the function from my script and execute a temporary filter accordingly. So I know I have the correct syntax for execution, e.g:

```
window.exportedApplyFilter(null, {name:"Mr. Rogers"});
```

The ﻿hangup is that I can't get that applyFilter function in any other way, e.g.

```
App.view.layout.someMagicObject.applyFilter(...);
```

Is there a way to access that function from another script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the Sugar team, I have an answer to my question. The solution is to pry in through the controller.layout object tree:

```
App.controller.layout.getComponent('sidebar').getComponent('main-pane')
```

This allows one to drill down to any Sidecar UI component and access the controller functions associated therewith. Perhaps not as elegant as other solutions, but it's readable.

If I wanted to take this further, I might write a short function to recurse through the subtree and look for the element with the correct CID number, then return the full path to it. CID numbers are progressive and advance depth-first, so the search would be pretty fast. But a hand search in the browser dev console only took minutes. Once that's found, accessing it again is a matter of a chain of getComponent(...) calls. The final return from the chain should be the element wanted (filter control, in my case) and should have the desired method as well.